# How to replace special symbols in a binary?

Tags: binary

I am trying to read a pdf from a URL, return it as a binary and replace some characters. This is working for plain text with the following code but if the pdf has any special symbols like Trademark, copyright etc then my webservice is unable to return the result. Can some one please help me how to achieve this. The output should definitely be a binary output :

```
String html="";
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream in = new URL(jsonobj.getString("xBody")).openStream();
int reads = in.read(); 
while(reads != -1){
 baos.write(reads); 
 reads = in.read(); 
}
html= baos.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `baos.toString()` internally calls `new String(buffer)`, which uses the default encoding (the encoding actually being used by your system, probably not `UTF-8`). Try to provide the encoding explicitly, as follows:

```
String html = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. With the earlier code, I got the error as follows -

java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x10' after '%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ

hÞbbd' is not a valid XML character.


And after modifying it with UTF-8 encoding I got the error as follows -

Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x10' after '%PDF-1.3
%????

h?bbd' is not a valid XML character.

Can you please help?

Comment: I think you forgot to add another part of code, isn't it? There are no XML logics involved in that snippet...